# How to connect OpenCover to VS tests

Tags: visual-studio, opencover

OpenCover 4.7.922 installed in VS 2015 Community, and appears in VS menu bar, but the link to my Tests is broken.  Project is a C# console app.

This was working a while ago, with the same project. Possibly disturbed by (1) installing VS 2019 (Now Community 2015 and 2019 are both installed) and (2) updating OpenCover.

OpenCover Text Explorer should find my tests, enabling me to run them.  But no tests are found. Likewise, under Test Explorer, "Run selected tests with OpenCover" is disabled (greyed out).

Comment: A little closer.  After adding NUnit and updating MSTest, the menu item Open Cover Test Explorer  shows the name of my test.  If I start it, though, the process appears to hang.  The OpenCover option in Test Explorer continues to be greyed out. Or, sometimes, "Could not find a part of the path ... \TestResults"

Answer (score 0):

It's working now.  Final stage was to delete the test project entirely and rebuild it, and make sure all projects use the same Target framework.

In summary, I am getting my code automatically colored (covered / not covered) using VS Community 2015, Target Framework 4.5.2, OpenCover 4.7.922, NUnit 3.12.0.